# ffmpeg how to create a effect video like: flower fall?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I try to create an effect video like: flower fall. I have a main video (main.mp4) and a effect video (flower_fall.mp4). I want to make a output.mp4 video that merge 2 this videos and the result look like main video is a bottom layer and effect video is a top layer(opacity about 0.5 or something like that).  What is the ffmpeg command for solve my target?

Comment: What's "flower fall"? Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Example I have a effect video like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDjntuzJL90. And i want the background of this video will be replaced by my video. My purpose is creating a falling flower effect for my video. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks guys. I used blend filter and it worked ok

Comment: Sorry for missing that. Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. From ffmpeg 1.2 or above, it supplied blend filter to make effect for video. Command for my problem is:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i bg.mp4 -filter_complex blend=all_expr='if(eq(mod(X,2),mod(Y,2)),A,B)' -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

I found this on internet and in researching how to use this filter. And, when we use the blend filter, it requires 2 inputs video must have the same width, height and SAR. I am in trouble with this. It is described details at: [FFmpeg: how to make output video has the same width, height, and SAR with input video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504084/ffmpeg-how-to-make-output-video-has-the-same-width-height-and-sar-with-input).
If you are interested in, please take a look this question and could help me. Thanks